# Fast method to create nested list with different types: numpy, pandas or list concatenation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I am trying to accelerate the code below that produces a list of lists with different types for each column. I originally created pandas dataframe and then converted it to list, but this seems to be fairly slow. How can I create this list faster, by say an order of magnitude? All columns are constant except one.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime

def overflow_check(x):
    # in SQL code the column is decimal(13, 2)
    p=13
    s=3
    max_limit = float("9"*(p-s) + "." + "9"*s)
    #min_limit =  0.01 #float("0" + "." + "0"*(s-2) + '1')
    #min_limit = 0.1
    if np.logical_not(isinstance(x, np.ndarray)) or len(x) < 1:
        raise Exception("Non-numeric or empty array.")
    else:
        #print(x)
        return x * (np.abs(x) < max_limit) + np.sign(x)* max_limit * (np.abs(x) >= max_limit)

def list_creation(y_forc):


    backcast_length = len(y_forc)

    backcast = pd.DataFrame(data=np.full(backcast_length, 2),
                            columns=['TypeId'])


    backcast['id2'] = None
    backcast['Daily'] = 1
    backcast['ForecastDate'] = y_forc.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    backcast['ReportDate'] = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    backcast['ForecastMethodId'] = 1
    backcast['ForecastVolume'] = overflow_check(y_forc.values)
    backcast['CreatedBy'] = 'test'
    backcast['CreatedDt'] = pd.to_datetime('today')


    return backcast.values.tolist()

i=pd.date_range('05-01-2010', '21-05-2018', freq='D')
x=pd.DataFrame(index=i, data = np.random.randint(0, 100, len(i)))

t=time.perf_counter()
y =list_creation(x)
print(time.perf_counter()-t)
```

Comment: I'd suggest returning the `backcast` dataframe, and applying the `values.tolist()` after.  That way you can better test where the bottle necks are.  I don't have enough experience with `pandas` to judge what's slow.  But it appears that you are creating the frame one `Series` at a time, which seems reasonable.  Constructing the list directly would require iterating overall times, building one sub list at a time.  I'm guessing that would scale poorly.

Comment: With a mix of dtypes (dataframe columns), you might be happier with a `backcast.to_records().tolist()` conversion, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @hpaulj seems similar in performance. I guess that one-by-one column additions are causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a bit faster, it just directly creates the list:

```
def list_creation1(y_forc):
    zipped = zip(y_forc.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), overflow_check(y_forc.values)[:,0])
    t = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    t1 =pd.to_datetime('today')
    return [
        [2, None, 1, i, t,
        1, v, 'test', t1] 
        for i,v in zipped
    ]


%%timeit
list_creation(x)
> 29.3 ms ± 468 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
list_creation1(x)
> 17.1 ms ± 517 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Edit: one of the large issues with the slowness is the time it takes to go from datetime to specified format. if we can get rid of that by phrasing it as the following:

```
def list_creation1(i, v):
    zipped = zip(i, overflow_check(np.array([[_x] for _x in v]))[:,0])
    t = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    t1 =pd.to_datetime('today')
    return [
        [2, None, 1, i, t,
        1, v, 'test', t1] 
        for i,v in zipped
    ]

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("05-01-2010", "%d-%m-%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("21-05-2018", "%d-%m-%Y")
i = [(start + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime("%d-%m-%Y") for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]
x=np.random.randint(0, 100, len(i))
```

Then this is now a lot faster:

```
%%timeit
list_creation1(i, x)
> 1.87 ms ± 24.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, @hchw,  I was wondering whether something can be done with numpy stuctures or something like that. I once resorted to numpy arrays instead of dataframes and the code accelerated by 2 orders of magnitude. But here I have different types, so not sure how to proceed. 50% faster doesn't seem to help a lot.

Comment: edited... this does not have much to do with dataframes at this point

Comment: But wouldn't this be faster because the slow operation is pushed outside the function definition? Another point that i didn't state clearly is that the datetime index of dataframe x might not be periodic, but have random gaps here and there.

Comment: my point is that the slowness of your function has nothing to do with pandas (anymore, after converting to list) but rather is nearly entirely the cost you must pay to go from datetime to strfttime

Comment: also, this does actually speed it up because list comprehension over dates is faster than df.index.strfttime()... if you put that inside the function the time is ~12 (still not as fast as you want, but this is now a separate issue)

Comment: Yes, you are right. `[str(i.year)+'-'+ str(i.month) + '-' + str(i.day) for i in x.index]` this seems to make it 5 times faster than `strftime`.